# Error message: '@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function' when trying to use 'let'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried scope functions in compose, but something confuses me.
I got error at place 1: '@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function', but I don't know why.

```
@Composable
fun scope_test() {
    val isOk: Boolean? = false
    Column() {
        isOk?.let {
            Text(text = "That's it!")
        } ?: {
            Text(text = "Nothing!") // place 1: error
        }
        isOk?.let {
            Text(text = "That's it!")
        } ?: run { Text(text = "Nothing!") }

        isOk?.let {
            Text(text = "That's it!")
        } ?: Text(text = "Nothing!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code blocks in Kotlin just don't execute by themselves. Even if in that block you use standard Kotlin statements the Android Studio will just grey them out, like they are redundant (they don't execute). You need to call the `run` function like you did in second example.

[Here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/anonymous-code-blocks-in-kotlin-versus-java/3250) is a similar question from Kotlin forums which I found helpful.